# Language file parse error

Tags: add-on-development

I have a language file in my foo add-on

```
<?php

$lang = array(

/* ----------------------------------------
/*  Required for MODULES page
/* ----------------------------------------*/

'foo_name'=>
'Foo',

'foo_description'=>
'Adds Foo information data in the field',

//-----------------------------------------//

/* END */
''=>''
);
?>
```

I got this error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/test/public_html/system/expressionengine/third_party/foo/language/english/foo_lang.php on line 1
```

Any idea why this is happening? I am probably missing something obvious.

Comment: Please post the actual language file that you have. It must me some typo, like a missing comma.

Comment: The code above is exactly what I have except for the word "Foo". I also ran it through a PHP syntax checker and it passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably either a problem with your text editor, or your FTP client (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11514498/odd-unexpected-t-variable).

Try copy pasting it into a new file and saving. Make sure the file is saved with unix line endings, and NO byte order mark (BOM).

Also try running it locally, instead of on your server, to rule out problems with your FTP client (assuming you're getting the error on a server, that is).

Comment: I found out that the problem is because of incompatible carriage returns in the client and server machines

Answer (score 0):

The file should be named `lang.foo.php`, not `foo_lang.php`

Comment: I tried it and it just gave me the same error

Comment: Do you need to uninstall and reinstall the add-on for the changes to reflect on EE?

Comment: No, there's no need to re-install in order to 'catch' changes in language file (assuming it as installed correctly)

Comment: Actually, `addon_name_lang.php` is the preferred file name. `lang.addon_name.php` is deprecated, but still works for backward compatibility.